# No consigo enviar parámetro usando GET a API REST node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs, api, rest

Tengo desarrollado una api rest en node js con un endpoint get que en función de un parámetro recibido, devuelve una serie de datos.
Estoy consumiendo la api desde jquery, pero no consigo enviarle ese parámetro que necesita en la petición get que hago. Si hago la petición desde Insomnia, me funciona perfectamente.

Este es el código del endpoint:

```
    async function getIncidentsByState(req,res){
    const params  = req.body;
    const completed = params.completed;
    
    console.log(completed);
    try {
        const incidents = await Incident.find({completed:completed}).sort({create_at:1});
        if(!incidents){
            res.status(400).send({msg:"Error al obtener las incidencias"});
        }
        else{
            res.status(200).send(incidents);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }
}
```

El código jquery que realiza la petición es el siguiente:

```
    function filtrarEstado(completed){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: {
            completed: true,
        },
        url: "http://localhost:3600/api/getIncidentsByState",
        
        success: function(data){
            mostrarIncidencias(data);
        }
    });
}
```

El parametro completed no está llegando a la api y está imprimiendo undefined.

He probado de decenas de formas distintas, pero no consigo hacerle llegar ese parámetro.

Agradecería sugerencias sobre lo que está pasando.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

La data que se via atra vez de HTTP GET esta en el query de la url, no en el body de la peticion.

Cambia:

```
async function getIncidentsByState(req,res)
{
  const params  = req.body;

//...
```

Por:

```
async function getIncidentsByState(req,res)
{
  const params  = req.query;

//...
```

Se utiliza `req.body` cuando es un apeticion `POST`.

Comment: El OP dice en su pregunta, que al hacer la petición con [*Insomnia*](https://insomnia.rest/) el endpoint funciona perfectamente, por lo tanto, el código del servidor es correcto. No es obligatorio enviar parámetros de consulta en la `url` mediante `query string`. Hay servidores que imponen límites al tamaño de una `url`. Enviarlos en el `body` es aceptable y permitido. Mi sugerencia es que edites tu respuesta y agregues que la misma es una de las formas de solucionar el problema, aunque no es la que pide el OP. Saludos

Comment: La respuesta que me ha dado Einer me funciona. Pero es cierto que me gustaría enviar los datos en el body, para que la url no fuera demasiado larga. ¿Alguna idea de por qué no puedo mandárselos al servidor con jquery en la petición ajax? Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas